# Enlarging the conditional formatting window in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-365

I use a lot of conditional formatting, often with relatively complex formulae to decide the format. Administering them, though, becomes a nuisance - the conditional formatting dialogue is too small and I have yet to find a way to resize it or the columns within it.

[image: Conditional formatting dialogue showing lack of space]

Is there any way to enlarge it, whether by normal means or by tweaking a config or something? It seems so outdated to have a fixed size on it with screens as large as they are now.

Comment: I wonder the same. My current workaround is to paste the formulas in notepad (well, technically in notepad++), edit them and then paste them back. But it full like a kludgy workaround.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's an easy way to do this, short of modifying the actual Excel application. Attempting to use the tool AutoSizer  (http://www.southbaypc.com/AutoSizer/) only resizes the window the list sits in, and not the list itself which seems to suggest the list size is hard-coded.

Perhaps the best way to work around this is by using a Formula Editor for Notepad++, which you can read more about here: http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2010/09/29/formula-editor-in-notepad/

At least this workaround offers some syntax highlighting and code folding (especially for large formula blocks).

Hope that helps!